# How does the angular.mock.module function know what module to address when mocking dependencies?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to figure out how the function `angular.mock.module` (often aliased to `window.module`) works. I understand its main usage is loading a module in your tests; that is easy:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("mymodule"));
```

This will load `myhmodule` before each `it` in my jasmine specs.

Another usage of `module` is to mock services/factories/values inside a certain module. Assuming `mymodule` has a value called `foo` of value `42` I can, in my specs, go like this:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("mymodule")); // this loads the module

// whereas this mocks the value of foo
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
   $provide.value("foo", 43);
});
```

My question is now the following: how does `module` know what module to address when mocking using the `$provide` service? In fact, in my test, I could have written:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("mymodule"));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("anothermodule"));

beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
   $provide.value("foo", 43);
});
```

Would this last snippet provide a `foo=43` to `mymodule` or `anothermodule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value("foo", 43);
}
```

This registers a new module providing a `foo` value. It doesn't add the value to any existing module.

Comment: So why is it used to mock existing services registered with existing modules? But most of all, how can it work at all?

Comment: Why is this new module capable of overriding pre-existing services? Simple cuz it was defined later on?

Comment: The answer to your last question is yes.